# How can I get a property attached to a global to stub properly with sinon?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sequelize.js, sinon, stub

I have a `helper.js` that loads before my tests:

```
before(async function() {
    this.timeout(30000)
    global.db = require(`${process.cwd()}/models`)()
    ...
```

Then in my test, I have:

```
describe.only('Phone Library', () => {
    let updateCallSpy
    beforeEach(() => {
        sinon.stub(twilioClient.calls, 'create').resolves({})
        updateCallSpy = sinon.stub(global.db.models.Call, 'update').resolves(true)
            // sinon.stub(global.db.models.Conversation, 'update').resolves({})
    })
```

The `twilioClient.calls.create` stubs properly. But the `global.db.models.Call.update` does not.

In my actual code, I'm using it like:

```
        await global.db.models.Call.update({ status: newCallStatus }, { where: { id: foundConversation.Call.id } })
```

When I `console.log(global.db.models.Call)`, it simply outputs `Call`. However, the `.update` function is there and does what it's supposed to do (a Sequelize model that updates).

I'm sure It's something terribly obvious, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequelize model methods are defined as `prototype` by the sequelize core.

The following should work

```
updateCallSpy = sinon.stub(global.db.models.Call.prototype, 'update').resolves(true)
```

You can also create a stub instance:

```
updateCallStubInstance = sinon.createStubInstance(global.db.models.Call)
```

Comment: I tried `updateCallSpy = sinon.stub(global.db.models.Call.prototype, 'update').resolves(true)`. Still no dice!

Comment: Which sequelize version are you using?